# Getting Heroku 503 error after trying to add aws storage for active storage image uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku, rails-activestorage

Made a photo sharing site with a rails api backend and react/redux frontend. Have backend of app on heroku, frontend on netlify.

Backend was working on heroku before I followed an article for getting aws storage for active storage image uploads set up. I was trying to do this because before deploying my app, image upload worked great. However, after deploying, images uploaded would disappear after a certain period of time, so thought I needed to store them with aws s3 storage now that the site was deployed.

However, after following the steps in that article, my heroku backend is no longer working and am getting this in heroku logs:

```
State changed from starting to crashed
2021-11-28T00:49:41.860576+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=photo-sharer-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=d4e71ac5-b919-4c86-add6-6087d2dce55a fwd="64.98.23.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-11-28T00:49:43.099228+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=photo-sharer-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=b6788a05-1014-4c0a-9ae0-37d20700f7be fwd="64.98.23.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here's how amazon section looks in storage.yml:

```yaml
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%=ENV['ACCESS_KEY']%>
  secret_access_key: <%=ENV['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']%>
  region: us-west-2
  bucket: <%=ENV['S3_BUCKET']%>`
```

Another thing I did from advice of the article was to put my access key, secret access key, and s3 bucket name for aws in my `.env` file.

Gem in gemfile for aws s3: `gem "aws-sdk-s3", "~> 1.106"`

Put this line in environments/development.rb for aws storage: `config.active_storage.service = :amazon`

Put this line in environments/production.rb for aws storage: `config.active_storage.service = :amazon`

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Just to be clear, you entered the values in the Heroku dashboard for those ENV variables and verified the names match, correct?

Comment: @RockwellRice Good call. I hadn't yet done that at that time, but did it recently. Not getting above error anymore but am getting a 403 error when trying to access my backend. Heroku build log shows 2 warnings. Are warnings like errors in the sense that they can completely stop the heroku backend from working?

Comment: Might be best to just ask another question if you are confused about it.  Hard to say what could be happening with no idea of what you are seeing.